# Why won't mysql query with my php script?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm trying to make this information insert into my table in mysql database with this script I wrote.

```
<?php
require("../includes/db.php");
$nme = $_POST["nme"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$address = $_POST["address"];
$city = $_POST["city"];
$state = $_POST["state"];
$zip = $_POST["zip"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$options = implode($_POST["options"],", ");
$query = mysql_query("insert into peeps (name, email, address, city, zip, phone, type) values ('$nme','$email','$address','$city','$state','$zip','$phone','$options')");
if($query)
    print "yes";
else
    print "no";
```

?>

The output of this code is no.

Comment: I can connect to my database fine.

Comment: `print mysql_error();` to see what is wrong.

Comment: @zachdyer You should not use the `mysql_` functions any more ([read more](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)).  Use the `mysqli` (notice the i) class instead. Also, you are open to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If mysql_query() returns false, it means the query failed.

Try this:

```
if (false === $query)  // make sure it's actually boolean false
  print mysql_error(); // print a nice plain-english description of the problem.
else
  print "Yes";
```

This should give you a good idea of where the problem is.

Comment: Thank you. 'state' did not exist in my table so I added it. Now it works great.

Answer (score 1):

If you modify this part of your code you can see the exact error you get.

```
if($query)
{
    print "yes";
}
else
{
    print mysql_error(); ;
}
```

However the way you have written may generate errors if you do not have enabled Magic Quotes. If you have that kind of error you better use `mysql_escape_string`